# Rewrite directive results in additional $_GET parameter using Nginx

Tags: php, apache, nginx

We just switched from Apache to nginx at my office.

The apaches rewrite rules looked like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /main.php?A=$1&B=$2&C=$3&D=$4&E=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /main.php?A=$1&B=$2&C=$3&D=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /main.php?A=$1&B=$2&C=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /main.php?A=$1&B=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /main.php?A=$1 [L]
```

The new Nginx rules are as follows:

```
rewrite ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /main.php?A=$1&B=$2&C=$3&D=$4&E=$5 last;
rewrite ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /main.php??A=$1&B=$2&C=$3&D=$4 last;
rewrite ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /main.php?A=$1&B=$2&C=$3 last;
rewrite ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /main.php?A=$1&B=$2 last;
rewrite ^([^/]*)/$ /main.php?A=$1 last;
```

Here's the issue, assuming we're accessing domain.com/frog/lemon/

```
<?php

/* Using Apache */
print_r( $_GET );
Array( [A] => 'frog' [B] => 'lemon' )

/* Using Nginx */
print_r( $_GET );
Array( [A] => [B] => [C] => 'lemon' )

?>
```

What's causing the additional array param ?

Bonus: I'm sure there a smarter way to code what I have above, how would you write your rewrites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the paths are passed with an initial / which before they didn't have?

Path `/frog/lemon/` will get caught by rule

```
^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$
```

as [^/]* will catch also ZERO chars.

`*` means: zero or more chars

`+` means: at least one char

If so, `/frog/lemon/`

becomes

```
^(zero chars here)/frog/lemon/$
```

hence A='',B='frog',C='lemon'

To fix it, try putting a `/` before the `[^/]*` like this:

```
rewrite ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /main.php?A=$1&B=$2&C=$3&D=$4&E=$5 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /main.php??A=$1&B=$2&C=$3&D=$4 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /main.php?A=$1&B=$2&C=$3 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /main.php?A=$1&B=$2 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]*)/$ /main.php?A=$1 last;
```

Maybe also put `+` instead of `*`, in all the params that can't be empty (can't be frog//lemon)

```
rewrite ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /main.php?A=$1&B=$2&C=$3&D=$4&E=$5 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /main.php??A=$1&B=$2&C=$3&D=$4 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /main.php?A=$1&B=$2&C=$3 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/$ /main.php?A=$1&B=$2 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/$ /main.php?A=$1 last;
```

Comment: I tried the replacing both just the first asterisk (per rule)' as well as all asterisks with the plus sign. No avail  all resulted in a 404. However, you're last example set above, with the additional slash, works perfectly - with the first query string param being 'A' & correctly populates $_GET super global. Thanks!

Comment: @user2977468 Sorry I just edited the answer, I had missed putting the / in front in the beginning, otherwise they won't catch the path /aaa/bbb/